# form input into array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, input

I've got a tool where i have to input some words, it has to go in:

```
$_POST['searchqueries']
```

.

I have multiple inputs in a form that has to come back in ['searchqueries'] looking like:
word1, word2, word3, word4.

This is what i have now, but it just comes back array, and not seperated

```
<fieldset style="border: none;">
<label for="searchquerie1">Zoekwoord 1:</label><input type="text" id="searchquerie1" name="searchqueries[]" maxlength="256" value="" /><br>
<label for="searchquerie2">Zoekwoord 2:</label><input type="text" id="searchquerie2" name="searchqueries[]" maxlength="256" value="" /><br>
<label for="searchquerie3">Zoekwoord 3:</label><input type="text" id="searchquerie3" name="searchqueries[]" maxlength="256" value="" /><br>
<label for="searchquerie4">Zoekwoord 4:</label><input type="text" id="searchquerie4" name="searchqueries[]" maxlength="256" value="" /><br>
<input type="hidden" name="fset"/>
</fieldset>
```

what do i have to do to make this work

Greetz

David

Comment: I don't know if i really get your question right.. but you can just change the name attribute from "searchqueries[]" to "word1", "word2", etc. and then the values will be transmitted in $_POST["word1"], $_POST["word2"]..

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) to glue elements in array together with `,` into a string.

say `$arr = array('a','b','c');`

```
$str = implode(',',$arr);
echo $str; // will output a,b,c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$combined = implode(',', $_POST['searchqueries']);
```

the string $combined with contains all the values seperated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)**

```
$varb = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searchqueries']);//sanitize the input
foreach($varb as $vals)
echo $vals['searchqueries'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you pass the values as array `searchqueries[]` you will retrieve an array…